# Camel unit test with cameltestsupport, template is always null

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-camel

I am doing a simple unit test with Camel. All I want to do is to read JSON content from a file (under resources), send it to a Java class for validation - this is the route that I am trying to test. Whatever I do, the template (which I use to *sendBody(json)* is always null. Here is my code:

```
public class RouteTests extends CamelTestSupport {

    @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:result")
    protected MockEndpoint resultEndpoint;

    @Produce(uri = "direct:start")
    protected ProducerTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    JSONObject testJson;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        try {
            final ObjectMapper objectmapper = new ObjectMapper();
            final ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            final InputStream stream = loader.getResourceAsStream("test.json");
            testJson = new JSONObject ((Map)objectmapper.readValue(stream, Map.class));

            // Start Camel
            context = new DefaultCamelContext();
            context.addRoutes(createRouteBuilder());
            context.start();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testSendMatchingMessage() throws Exception {
        //resultEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceived(expectedBody);
        resultEndpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:result");
        //resultEndpoint = context.getEndpoint("mock:result", MockEndpoint.class);
        resultEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);
        template.sendBody("direct:start", testJson);
        resultEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("direct:start")
                        .filter().method(ValidationProcessor.class, "validate")
                        .to("mock:result");
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected JndiRegistry createRegistry() throws Exception {
        JndiRegistry jndi = super.createRegistry();
        jndi.bind("ValidationProcessor", new ValidationProcessor", ());

        return jndi;
    }
}
```

Problems I faced:

1. Initially the result end point also was always null. (I used *[FilterTest.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/components/camel-test/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/test/patterns/FilterTest.java)* for reference). Then I had to do an explicit

   ```
    resultEndpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:result");
   ```

   to resolve that.
2. Then I read that I had to override the createRegistry, but I did not know how to bind. I just used the name of my validation class, but I don’t know if this is right.

   But the template is always null. The [null pointer exception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_pointer#Dereferencing) (NPE) is at

   ```
    template.sendBody("direct:start", testJson);
   ```

Please also point me to some reading if necessary. The reference code that Apache Camel documentation link to did not even have the starting of the Camel that I do in the setUp method.

Comment: You should not create CamelContext yourself but let `CamelTestSupport` create it for you. As part of its setup it setup some of the IoC stuff. But mind you have have Spring `@Autowired` in there which is not Camel and if so you would need to extend `CamelSpringTestSupport` instead. See the unit tests in camel-test-spring if you use Camel and Spring together. Also the CiA2 book has a full chapter on testing.

Comment: Will follow your advice, thanks.
I am also going to read that book chapter you referred to.

Comment: Is that when createRegistry overriding is required? I am still not clear about that even though the below solution works :D

Comment: Overriding createRegistry is a neat trick to allow to bind beans from java code, which can be a bit more tricky when using spring. Chapter 4 in the books covers the various Camel Registry implementations.

Comment: I don't think the code compiles - near `jndi.bind("ValidationProcessor", new ValidationProcessor",` (this is also in the initial revision). This is indicated by the strange syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've missed out on a lot of the really helpful stuff that `CamelTestSupport` does for you.  It has its own `setUp` method that you should override.  I believe your test should really look something like this:

```
public class RouteTests extends CamelTestSupport {

    private JSONObject testJson;

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        // REALLY important to call super
        super.setUp();

        ObjectMapper objectmapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        InputStream stream = loader.getResourceAsStream("test.json");
        testJson = new JSONObject(objectmapper.readValue(stream, Map.class));
    }

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() {
                from("direct:start")
                        .filter().method(ValidationProcessor.class, "validate")
                        .to("mock:result");
            }
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void testSendMatchingMessage() throws Exception {
        MockEndpoint resultEndpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:result");
        resultEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);
        template.sendBody("direct:start", testJson);
        resultEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }
}
```

Actually I would remove the override of `setUp` altogether and put the reading of the test data in to the test method itself.  Then it's clear what the data is being used for and you can eliminate the `testJson` field.

```
public class RouteTests extends CamelTestSupport {

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() {
                from("direct:start")
                        .filter().method(ValidationProcessor.class, "validate")
                        .to("mock:result");
            }
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void testSendMatchingMessage() throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper objectmapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        InputStream stream = loader.getResourceAsStream("test.json");
        JSONObject testJson = new JSONObject(objectmapper.readValue(stream, Map.class));

        MockEndpoint resultEndpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:result");
        resultEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);
        template.sendBody("direct:start", testJson);
        resultEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }
}
```

There, much simpler.

Comment: Will certainly try this out and post back, thanks for such a detailed reply :)

Comment: Of course it worked! Thanks much, it is so much simpler. So in my case why was template or resultEndPoint null ?? I just dont get it. 
The FilterTest at http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/components/camel-test/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/test/patterns/FilterTest.java just did not work :(

Comment: tbh I'm not sure really.  I don't tend to use the @-annotations and generally write my route tests this way.

Comment: Is there any clean up that we need to do between tests? The reason I ask is the first test (with a positive o/p JSON) finished in 1 ms and the immediate second test (with an expected failure) takes 10 seconds. It just stops for awhile, so I was wondering if something needs to be reset between each test

Comment: When you do `resultEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied()` it waits to allow any in-flight asynchronous exchanges to complete before failing.  The default is ten seconds, as noted here: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/mock-component.adoc#simple-example

Comment: @butwad Gotcha, thanks a ton for all the help man. Most appreciated. On a completely unrelated note, do you know if rabbitmq dlq has anything to do with autoAck?????!!

Comment: No, can't help with rabbitmq I'm afraid.  Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer!

Comment: Writing more junit test cases, I realized that my ValidationProcessor class has Autowired beans in them (elastic search client). But they always result in NPE. So how do I make the autowired components work while executing camel route?

Comment: Assuming you won't be convinced that autowiring is ultimately a bad practice, take a look at Camel's Spring testing support: http://camel.apache.org/spring-testing.html

Answer (score 2):

Try to create the producertemplate from the Camel context as so:

```
public class RouteTests extends CamelTestSupport {

    @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:result")
    protected MockEndpoint resultEndpoint;

    protected ProducerTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    JSONObject testJson;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        try {
            final ObjectMapper objectmapper = new ObjectMapper();
            final ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            final InputStream stream = loader.getResourceAsStream("test.json");
            testJson = new JSONObject ((Map)objectmapper.readValue(stream, Map.class));
            //start camel
            context = new DefaultCamelContext();
            context.addRoutes(createRouteBuilder());
            context.start();
            template = context.createProducerTemplate();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testSendMatchingMessage() throws Exception {
        //resultEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceived(expectedBody);
        resultEndpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:result");
        //resultEndpoint = context.getEndpoint("mock:result", MockEndpoint.class);
        resultEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);
        template.sendBody("direct:start", testJson);
        resultEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("direct:start")
                        .filter().method(ValidationProcessor.class, "validate")
                        .to("mock:result");
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected JndiRegistry createRegistry() throws Exception {
        JndiRegistry jndi = super.createRegistry();
        jndi.bind("ValidationProcessor", new ValidationProcessor());

        return jndi;
    }
}
```

So in your setUp() just add:

```
template = context.createProducerTemplate();
```

And remove `@Produce(uri = "direct:start")`.

Comment: That worked, great thanks :)
But is the createRegistry even required???

Comment: BTW, what was my issue? I would still like to understand where I am missing what? IF you can explain it would be so helpful :)

Comment: This answer doesn't take advantage of `CamelTestSupport` - there's no need to create the context or template yourself.