# CamelTestSupport with routes using classes with @Autowired

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-test

After help from experts over at question *[Camel unit test with cametestsupport, template is always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49118176/camel-unit-test-with-cametestsupport-template-is-always-null)*, I ended up with one more issue.

Below is my test class - a simple test that tests a route which has only ValidationProcessor [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object).

```java
public class RouteTests extends CamelTestSupport {

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() {
                from("direct:start")
                        .filter().method(ValidationProcessor.class, "validate")
                        .to("mock:result");
            }
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void testSendMatchingMessage() throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper objectmapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        InputStream stream = loader.getResourceAsStream("test.json");
        JSONObject testJson = new JSONObject(objectmapper.readValue(stream, Map.class));

        MockEndpoint resultEndpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:result");
        resultEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);
        template.sendBody("direct:start", testJson);
        resultEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }
}
```

The problem comes when this ValidationProcessor has an `@Autowired` component in it. My validation method needs data from Elasticsearch and hence I have an `@Autowired` for an elastic client.

When I run `mvn clean test`, I am getting a `NullPointerException` stating that this elastic client is null. I think the issue is that this test is devoid of anything to do with Spring and hence the issue, but I do not know how to overcome this.

My test needs to fetch data from Elasticsearch and hence the ValidationProcessor POJO does need `@Autowired`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I've discovered is that it's *unwise* to extend `CamelTestSupport` when you want to use anything with Spring.  In fact, there's a better way to do it - use the `CamelSpringBootRunner` instead.

Well...I say "better".  You're going to find yourself attaching a ton of annotations.  Of the things you'll need:

- A boostrapper to ensure that you're bootstrapping Camel correctly
- The routes you wish to add to the classpath (and all of the beans); this ensures that they get added to Camel's registry through Spring's registry
- You have to dirty the context after every run or your tests get into a wonky state.
- You can automock endpoints by specifying either `@MockEndpoints` or `@MockEndpointsAndSkip`.  The former sends the data along to the actual route.

Below is just a start.  Many of these annotations and their documentation can be found [in the formal docs](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-test-spring/src/main/docs/test-spring.adoc).

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)
@BootstrapWith(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(classes = { YourEntryPointClass.class })
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@UseAdviceWith
@MockEndpoints("direct:*")
public class RouteTests {

}
```

Comment: What is YourEntryPoint.class? Is it my Spring application? Also where do I specify routes? Can I just pass a RouteBuilder somewhere?

Comment: @ananth: Yes, that'd be the class annotate with `@SpringBootApplication`. I've taken a different approach with my testing of routes; I've always held that the declaration of routes in my tests felt artificial and fake, and I'd rather wire them in through Spring directly so I *knew* what I was testing. I'd recommend that you wire in your actual routes here.  You can specify them just fine, and you can exclude the ones you don't want using `"camel.springboot.java-routes-exclude-pattern=**/RoutesYouDontWantToInclude"`. as a property value in your `@SpringBootTest` annotation.

Comment: Can you point me to a sample class implementation? I am not getting the hang of the strategy you are suggesting. For example, I dont want to use my actual routes of my app as they have rabbit endpoints. My aim of this testing is only to test the POJOs that participate in the route. That is why I re-define the route in my test. Is no part of my existing test usable? In your way, how do we start camel, add routes to the context etc etc? I think I am going to keep hammering out questions, so it would help if you can point out some implementation that I can refer (and stop bugging you :D )

Comment: You're going to want to look at `@UseAdviceWith` and weaving routes in.  It's explained in the documentation.  It's trivial to *not* send your data to the RabbitMQ routes and instead substitute those for `seda:` endpoints instead using that.

Comment: If CamelSpringTestSupport extends CamelTestSupport shouldnt that be usable? (this is in the very beginning of the documentation)?

Comment: No; you'll want to just go whole hog in with the annotations here.  You don't need to extend anything.

Answer (score 4):

When you extend `CamelTestSupport` then it's *not* a Spring application. You need to extend `CamelSpringTestSupport`. That would create Camel in a Spring runtime, and then allow beans to have [IoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) via Spring. This kind of testing is often used with Camel XML routes where the routes are defined in XML files. However, you can have a plain XML file and refer to routes in Java DSL as well.

However, as [Makoto answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49266251/cameltestsupport-with-routes-using-classes-with-autowired/49266522#49266522), then vanilla Spring unit testing is of late often about using all those gazillion annotations. Camel has support for that as well as his answer shows. This is also how for example Spring Boot testing is done, etc.

You can find some unit tests in `camel-test-spring` you can use as inspiration as well.